# How can I set color for listing executable files in Dired Mode?

Tags: dired, colors

Trying here to set color for executable files, as it is for ls command!

How can I do that?

I've already managed to set color for certains file extensions, using Diredful package, but couldn't do it according to it's mode!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define "executable file" and a file's "mode".

If you mean something that `ls` recognizes as executable and flags as such, with an asterisk (`*`), when you use `ls` switch `F`, then [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) highlights that.  It uses face `` for the asterisk.

```lisp
;; For this to show up, you need `F' among the options in `dired-listing-switches'.
;; For example, I use "-alF" for `dired-listing-switches'.
(defface diredp-executable-tag
    '((t (:foreground "Red")))
  "Face used for executable tag (*) on file names in Dired buffers."
  :group 'Dired-Plus :group 'font-lock-highlighting-faces)
```

Comment: Would you know how I could install Dired+?

As of Emacs 26 it doens't seems to be available in MELPA Stable!

Comment: See [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus). The library is here: [`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el). Put it in a directory that is in your `load-path` (user option), then put `(require 'dired)` in your init file.

Comment: That just worked swiftly!

But my problem I've solved with `diredful-add`, then named Type Name, which was Executables. In pattern I entered `$*`, to match those binaries with `*` at the end!

And in Pattern Type just selected the last option, which was "Regexp on whole line (starting from the first permission column) including file name."

So that way now I see the executable files highlighted in colors in Dired mode itself, and not only in Shell mode!

Answer (score 0):

For a non-dired-plus version, I use this code to highlight executable files in `dired-mode` by using the face `helm-ff-executable` (it can be changed to any other face up to preference):

```lisp
(add-to-list
   'dired-font-lock-keywords
   (list dired-re-exe
         '(".+" (dired-move-to-filename) nil (0 'helm-ff-executable)))
   'append)
```